# Extract zipped file from another zip archive

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I'm working with powershell 5.1.17134.590 and would like to know if there's a way to extract a zipped file from inside another zip without copying to another folder first, please

Something like this, where the only extraction would be from the file.zip content :

```
Expand-Archive -LiteralPath arquive.zip\file.zip -DestinationPath c:\somefolder
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem like this is possible with Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive, it seems to be limited to basic level compression/decompression - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/?view=powershell-6

I've found a couple of posts where someone has used System.IO.Compression.FileSystem instead to achieve this goal:

https://techibee.com/powershell/reading-zip-file-contents-without-extraction-using-powershell/2152

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c60d8b4e-9408-45c1-bb32-00c53586bd58/unzipping-nested-files-in-powershell?forum=winserverpowershell

Comment: Thanks @Skud. It's very much what I was looking for! 

Not the one line way that expected for haha but very helpful indeed